# Auto List Generation with INDEX MATCH or script?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I hope to get some help automating my COVID-19 Swab testing spreadsheet.

Here is an example spreadsheet:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vi6Dd0UV_E6tnisC3Na_zCxeLC_3DrLr/view?usp=sharing

Only pay attention to the first 4 TABs.

The tab 'Crew List' gets updated about every week or so with the total list of Employees.

When this happens, I would like each of the departmental tabs to get Automatically populated with all the Crew members in their department but I cannot seem to get INDEX MATCH to work properly.

I was also hoping for a clear command to clear the test results (G:N) from all the departments tabs as this will be a live document that other spreadsheets will grab data from and replacing it even with the same file name produces errors.

If you see my work in the spreadsheet and have other suggestions please let me know!

Many Thanks!
Larson

EDIT:
I tried using a method found in this website: exceldemy.com/excel-generate-list-based-on-criteria This one: =IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$12, MATCH(0, IF(G$2=$C$2:$C$12, COUNTIF($G$2:$G2, $B$2:$B$12), ""), 0)),"") but changing the cell references obviously and I've only gotten it to return one result with the wrong referenced cell returned (such as returning the Last name where the First name should go)

EDIT2:
This formula placed into the Rest. Serv Tab worked to return the proper ID of the first employee:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Crew List'!$B$4:$B$19, MATCH(0, IF($B$1='Crew List'!$E$4:$E$19, COUNTIF($B$1:$B$1, 'Crew List'!$B$2:$B19), ""), 0)),"")
```

SOLUTION:
Thank you so much for your help, I have used your formula successfully pasting it into Cell B3 of each departments tab but I have slightly modified the code to eliminate any errors for departments that do not have any employees and also because each department tab has the name of the department in Cell B1 I used this formula:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Crew List'!B4:F1000,'Crew List'!E4:E1000=B1),"")
```

As far as a VBA Script to clear out the test results, I have found success with this (Incomplete):

```
Sub ClearValueOnly()

Worksheets("Audio Visual Media").Range("G3:N1000").ClearContents
Worksheets("Aux Serv").Range("G3:N1000").ClearContents
Worksheets("Rest. Service").Range("G3:N1000").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: I tried using a method found in this website:
https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-generate-list-based-on-criteria/
This one:
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$12, MATCH(0, IF(G$2=$C$2:$C$12, COUNTIF($G$2:$G2, $B$2:$B$12), ""), 0)),"")
but changing the cell references obviously and I've only gotten it to return one result with the wrong referenced cell returned (such as returning the Last name where the First name should go)

Comment: Edit your post to add this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, several things here.

First, you want the function `FILTER()` for extracting (possible) multiple lines of data. `VLOOKUP()`, `XLOOKUP()`, and `INDEX/MATCH` all provide single line returns in their normal usage methods.

`FILTER()` will provide the entire row if desired, for each matching entry. So with the data shown, you'd use a formula like this, adjusted for actual sheets and ranges:

```
=FILTER('Crew List'!B4:N19,'Crew List'!E4:E19="REST. SERVICE")
```

which would return two entries, Stanley Sands and Ican Designer. Which solves the main problem.

There are finer points in its use. For instance, one can use another `FILTER()` wrapped around it to return only chosen columns from the B:N columns. For that one's criteria, one would use an array constant of 1's (TRUE) and 0's (FALSE), one for each column to show to keep it or ditch it. So to keep columns B, C, D, I, and J, you'd use `{1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0}`. Or one could use `INDEX()` instead and specify the columns by number (not column number on the sheet, like column B = 2, but by their places in the range given, like column B = 1) in a similar array constant (like `{1,2,3,8,9}`).

Then the desire to clear old data before bringing in the new. How this would be done depends upon one's skills and proclivities, as well as needs. For instance, needs. If you wish the data pulled from the Crew List sheet, for example, to be retained on the sub-sheets that pulled it, only being gone on the Crew List sheet, then you need VBA or a lot of manual work since Excel's formulas do not take actions on entered data. They will look for data and display or otherwise use it in however many places you like, but they never DO anything. So to keep the old extracted data, you'd need to do it yourself, one way or the other. The file is an .XLSM so someone is apparently using VBA in it, and this would be relatively easy to write for someone.

If you want the data gone everywhere and only new data based upon the updated listings to be in place, `FILTER()` only cares that you CLEAR the data, not delete the rows, columns, and certainly sheets, that it is looking at for new data. So selecting the Crew List data range (probably over-selecting so that its variable number of rows did not hurt you one week) and clearing it by pressing the delete key or equivalently would do the trick. The sub-sheets would see the data disappear and it would be gone from them too. When the new data was pasted in, by whatever method, but again, not by a method that moved rows and such, the sub-sheets would pull appropriately from it without missing a beat.

So it comes down to selecting and clearing the current data. Manually? There's a neat trick that would make it fast and easy. VBA? Many ways, all perfectly fine. Remember though (as I stress again), do not affect the structure of things by deleting or inserting rows. Paste the data in in some manner.

So, neat trick. Create a Named Range that specifies a sufficient range in its `Refers to` box. So, say you expect perhaps 20-30 entries maximum. Then use a range like B4:N103 to be awful sure you always get everything. Once the Named Range is created, if you look in the box to the left of the Formula Editor above the column letters, you can find it there. Just click on it and select the Named Range. Your data area will be selected and just press `Delete` to wipe it. That's it. Pretty easy.

If you can, and don't mind, writing a macro, you could do that too. But the above is really easy.

In case I wasn't clear enough when mentioning how clearing the source data each week would clear it on the sub-sheets as well (because the formulas will not find anything to display when the data is gone and not yet replaced), it just isn't a problem. Clearing it at its source will clear it on the sub-sheets.

Next thing is that your example of what you want cleared was columns G:N, not B:N. As if you want to keep old material for columns B:F. This approach will not work for that. Not in a single formula and not without a lot of manual work or VBA.

For example, each sub-sheet could have a `FILTER()` formula for the data in columns B:F and for the data in columns G:N. You'd have to convert the current formula results to data on those sub-sheets and clear the second set for them. But this also implies you want to fill in the G:N area with the new data, even though the new data could clearly be pretty fully new, adding and deleting crew so nothing would match or be valid.

So the statements lead to contradiction. My guess is that you are just saying the things because you are working out ways things can be done, and are not really aware of how `FILTER()` can repopulate all columns from the new data sets, so one need not retain the B:F material as the formula would pull it as well. So all would work nicely. But guesses can be quite wrong, so...

To recap, the idea would be to use the arrays of data the given formula would pull to each sheet. Every time a new set was ready for import, one would use the Named Range selection technique to quickly wipe out the old. One would then import the new data and the formulas would repopulate as appropriate. All easy to do without VBA or any serious effort. But one could certainly use VBA for all of it if one desires and has the time to write it.

And if archiving of the sub-sheets' current data before importing new data replacing it is mandatory, VBA is your best shot given the very many sheets needing checking and work. Especially if it is one of the more complex paths I was mentioning above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have used your formula successfully pasting it into Cell B3 of each departments tab but I have slightly modified the code to eliminate any errors for departments that do not have any employees and also because each department tab has the name of the department in Cell B1 I used this formula:
=IFERROR(FILTER('Crew List'!B4:F1000,'Crew List'!E4:E1000=B1),"")

As far as a VBA Script to clear out the test results, I have found success with this (Incomplete):
Sub ClearValueOnly()
Worksheets("Audio Visual Media").Range("G3:N1000").ClearContents
etc
End Sub